# Concurrent system calls handling by kprobes

Tags: http, linux-kernel, ebpf, kprobe

I have written an **eBPF** program which captures HTTP **requests** and **responses** using **kprobes** on system calls like `accept4`, `accept`, `read`, `write`, `close`(both entry & exit) and sending these as a captured event to userspace using ringbuf.
I have few questions which i am unable to find out.

1. How many concurrent requests this setup can handle?
2. Since i was missing some **kretprobes** on `read` system call due to low default value of `maxactive` parameter (determines number of **kretprobes** instances), so i have set this to some value say 1024(max = 4096). I know that even at this maximum value some **kretprobes** will be ignored. But still how much it can handle say i am on 2 core cpu.
3. So i will set this `maxactive` parameter to all of the above mentioned syscall **kretprobe**, what can be the **overhead**?

I have limited familiarity with eBPF and its concepts, please help.

Architecture: **x86_64**

Kernel Version: **5.15+**